# ClassCastException when trying to apply custom filter in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm using 4.10.3 solr and after I implemented Factory with Filter

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory;

import java.util.Map;

public class CustomFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory {

protected CustomFilterFactory(Map<String, String> args) {
    super(args);
}

@Override
public TokenStream create(TokenStream tokenStream) {
    return new CustomFilter(tokenStream);
}
}
```

and when Solr starts, I'm getting strange errors in log:

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.tr.ApostropheFilterFactory
at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3116)
at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.next(SPIClassIterator.java:141)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.reload(AnalysisSPILoader.java:79)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.<init>(AnalysisSPILoader.java:60)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.<init>(AnalysisSPILoader.java:49)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory.<clinit>(TokenFilterFactory.java:31)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:474)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:593)
at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader$1.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:306)
at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader$1.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:299)
at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:151)
at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.readAnalyzer(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:325)
at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:95)
at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:43)
at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:151)
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:486)
```

Any idea what could cause this state?

Field definition:

```
<field name="ii" type="customFilter" indexed="true" stored="false"  required="false" multiValued="false"/>
<fieldType name="customFilter" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="com.nosql.search.solr.CustomFilterFactory" /> 
    </analyzer> 
</fieldType>
```

I'm using same Java version for my custom jar with filter and for starting Solr.

It works if I remove the reference to CustomFilterFactory.

Comment: The errors seems to be caused by the ApostropheFilterFactory? Have you tried with a small subset as possible of the actual config and with your class? How is the field defined? Does it work if you remove the reference to CustomFilterFactory? Are your filter compiled with the same Java version as the Solr distribution (and are the JVM version you're running Solr on compatible with both)? I suggest recompiling Solr by yourself as well, so you're eliminating any issues with JVM versions while developing as well

Comment: **Are your filter compiled with the same Java version as the Solr distribution (and are the JVM version you're running Solr on compatible with both)?** I'm using same Java version for my custom jar with filter and for starting Solr

Comment: You're loading your filter as a CharFilter - you might want to try extending `BaseCharFilter` and implement the required methods instead.

Comment: Well, I've changed tag from **<charFilter>** to **<filter>** - same problem.

Comment: So I was banned to post answer to a question, so will post a workaround to my comment that helped me :

It seems I've managed to work this around. I had custom classpath, that was containing lucene lib from cloudera *(4.10.3-cdh5.4.0 version)* with **org.apache.lucene.analysis.tr.ApostropheFilterFactory**, and had embedded Tomcat Solr application that had its own classpath in **/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib/** folder that contained lucene *(4.10.3)* library version. After removing moving my custom filter into webapp classpath and removing all libs from custom classpath everything began to work

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Solr 6.4. But my solr is deployed within the Hybris 6 framework. The point is that I tried to add my custom token filter library directly to solr server libraries ${solr_instance}/server/lib, then I got an exception that the engine could find the parent lucene class TokenFilterFactory. After the adding of the related jars lucene-analysers-common-x, lucene-core-x, I got the same error as yours (java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.tr.ApostropheFilterFactory)

To resolve this I just moved my custom jar to the custom folder ${solr_instance}/contrib/hybris/lib without any additional lucene libs. Moreover my solrconfig.xml already had a link to it:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/hybris/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

So, one can conclude that this kind of exception refers to classpath ambiguity issue, which confuses Solr.